# How to use mapply properly

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I have data frame `all_vars_ready_2016`. I what to apply `table` function with `exclude=NULL` argument to that data frame in order to get frequency tables of all variables of data frame. This works:

```
mapply(table, all_vars_ready_2016)
```

I tried to add `exclude=NULL` argument in several ways but non of them succeed. What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: I don't think `mapply` is the best tool for this. Try `sapply`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik can you please provide code for that applies table function with exclude=NULL argument to every variable in data frame with `sapply`?

Comment: You can use an anonymous function `mapply(function(x) table(x, exclude = NULL), all_vars_ready_2016)`. But as Roman notes, `mapply` is meant for cases when you're applying over >1 variable (although it will still work with only one)

Comment: @IceCreamToucan can you please provide code for that applies table function with exclude=NULL argument to every variable in data frame with `sapply`?

Comment: Edit: actually, you probably want `lapply` (hard to know,  I suggest showing expected output) `lapply(all_vars_ready_2016, function(x) table(x, exclude = NULL))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(all_vars_ready_2016, table, exclude = NULL)
```

the ... argument allows you to specify additional arguments of functions

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to correctly call the function with:

```
mapply(table, all_vars_ready_2016, exclude = FALSE)
```

not `exclude = NULL`.

At least it works here.

However, I prefer using `map` from the `purrr` package like

```
purrr::map(all_vars_ready_2016, table, exclude = FALSE)
```